# How to set up phpcs with WordPress coding standard with PHP8?

Tags: php, coding-standards

Trying to set up `PHP_CodeSniffer` with the [WordPress Codings Standards](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress-Coding-Standards). I'm running `PHP v8.0.3` and `phpcs v3.5.8.` (in March 2021).

WPCS is installed via

```
git clone -b master https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress-Coding-Standards.git wpcs
```

The installation worked, but running phpcs leads to this error:

```
phpcs: Uncaught TypeError: vsprintf(): Argument #2 ($values) must be of type array, 
string given in file.php
```

This is apparently an [issue](https://github.com/squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer/issues/3196) with WPCS and fixed in this [commit](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress-Coding-Standards/commit/7cd46bed1e6a7a2af3fe24c7f4a044da3076d8f4). The commit seems to be not merged into *master* yet, so I checked out the *develop* branch.
This appears to fix the above-mentioned issue but causes another error:

```
phpcs: Referenced sniff "PHPCSUtils" does not exist
```

The proposed [solution](https://github.com/squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer/issues/3110) for fixing this issue is switching to the *master* branch, which brings me back to square one.

So both *`master`* and *`develop`* don't work for different reasons. I guess could change the source code in the master branch manually, but that doesn't seem to be a sustainable fix.

Is there a better way to make phpcs work with the current versions of PHP and WPCS?

Comment: Have you tried using `composer` to install it instead? Have you raised an issue on the github repo?

Comment: Installed via `composer` I also get `phpcs: Uncaught TypeError: vsprintf(): Argument #2 ($values) must be of type array, string given in /home/user/.config/composer/vendor/squizlabs/php_codesniffer/src/Files/File.php:1050`

Comment: I wasn't sure if raising an issue would be appropriate, both errors are already issues in the project. The fix is just not merged yet. The latest release is May 2020, that's why I thought I'm just doing something wrong. I don't think I'm the only person trying to use PHP8, so others must have make it work.

Comment: Don't be hesitant about making comments / asking about progress on the GitHub ticket. Who knows, you might actually remind someone to merge the fix into `master`.

Comment: I did, but it wasn't received that well. I tried to be polite, but I'm not a native speaker.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently PHPCS ([link to issue](https://github.com/squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer/issues/3182#issue-758524292)) and WPCS ([link to issue](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress-Coding-Standards/issues/1967#issue-770860444)) do not work at this point with PHP8 and won't until their next releases.

It's therefore recommended to use PHP 7.4 instead.

### "Hack" option

Before downgrading my system to PHP7, I tried this hack. It seems to work for me, at least for the brief testing I did. But it might cause any kinds of issues, so **use it at you own risk**.

Replacing the content of the local `ControlStructureSpacingSniff.php` file
(*in `/WordPress/Sniffs/WhiteSpace/` of the cloned repo or the vendor folder of the composer installation*) with the [one](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/WordPress/WordPress-Coding-Standards/develop/WordPress/Sniffs/WhiteSpace/ControlStructureSpacingSniff.php) from the `develop` branch.

Answer (score 2):

In June 2023, this issue is still happening with PHP 8.2.4, PHPCS version 3.7.2 (stable) and [the latest stable WPCS release 2.3.0](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress-Coding-Standards/releases/tag/2.3.0)

A quick workaround until a stable release is to go to file `.\php\pear\PHP\CodeSniffer\src\Files\File.php` (around line 1056) and replace this code:

```
if (empty($data) === false) {
    $message = vsprintf($message, $data);
}
```

with this one:

```
if (empty($data) === false) {
    if (is_array($data)) {
        $message = vsprintf($message, $data);
    } else {
        $message = sprintf($message, $data);
    }
 }
```